# Chrome Extensions Notifications - How do I send a value to the notification and re-use it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I am writing a very simple chrome extension. I need the ability to fire off a specific url based on the data that is passed to the notification. Using ajax, or whatever, I would dynamically create a notification call that the user would click to launch the url. The extension also reads in omnibox data to launch a similar URL.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Quick Search ",
  "description": "Quickly search",
  "omnibox": {
    "keyword": "#"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "notifications",
    "http://url.ineed.com/"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "rugbyball.png",
    "32": "rugbyball32.png",
    "128": "rugbyball128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
"browser_action":{
    "default_icon":"rugbyball.png"
},
  "version": "1.0",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "9",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js

```
function resetDefaultSuggestion() {
  chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({
    description: '#: Search for %s'
  });
}

resetDefaultSuggestion();

chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(function(text, suggest) {
  // Suggestion code will end up here.
});

chrome.omnibox.onInputCancelled.addListener(function() {
  resetDefaultSuggestion();
});

function navigate(url) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: url});
  });
}

chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function(text) {
  navigate("https://url.ineed.com?param=" + text);
});

chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(closeNotification);

function closeNotification(evt) {
    console.log('click event ' + evt);
    navigate("https://url.ineed.com/");
}

var Notification=(function (){
    var notification= null ;         
    return   {         
        display: function (opt){             
            notification=chrome.notifications.create(opt);             
        },         
        hide: function (){             
            notification.close();
        }
    };
})();

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function (windowId){
    var   opt = {         
        type:  "basic" ,         
        title:  "Message" ,         
        message:  "New " ,         
        iconUrl:  "rugbyball128.png"     
    };
Notification.display(opt);
});
```

tl;dr - Need a way to pass a param to the notification and open a url with that data.

Comment: You're mixing web `Notification` and `chrome.notifications`. Which one do you actually need?

Comment: chrome.notifications should be fine. This will be specific to the chrome extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use unique self-deregistering listeners for clicks.

```
function createNotification(url, createdCallback) { // callback is optional
  var opt = { /* ... */ };
  chrome.notifications.create(opt, function(createdId) {
    var handler = function(id) {
      if(id == createdId) {
        navigate(url);
        chrome.notifications.clear(id);
        chrome.notifications.onClicked.removeListener(handler);
      }
    };
    chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(handler);
    if(typeof createdCallback == "function") createdCallback();
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow, yeah this is exactly what I needed. I got a bit too caught up on trying to pass a parameter, that I ignored the idea of just passing the entire URL. This is perfect, thank you!